# How recursion works in a code for computing Permutations of a number

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, permutation

I have found this code the internet to computer all possible Permutations for a given Vector ..

```
import java.util.Vector;

class Permute {
    static int count = 0;

    public static void permute(Vector unvisited, Vector visited) {
    if ( unvisited.isEmpty() ) {
        System.out.println("Permutation: "+visited);
        count++;
    }
    else { 
        //System.out.println("Trace: "+visited+" "+unvisited);
        int l = unvisited.size();
        for(int i = 0; i<l; i++) {
        String next = String.valueOf(unvisited.remove(i));
        visited.add(next);
        permute(unvisited,visited);
        unvisited.add(i,next);
        visited.remove(next);
        }
    }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Vector objects = new Vector();

    objects.add(1);
    objects.add(5);
    objects.add(8);

    permute(objects, new Vector() );
        System.out.println(count+" Permutationen gefunden");
    }
}
```

Bu I have a small problem in understanding the code and the flow of the instructions .
What I misses is when these two lines are called

```
    unvisited.add(i,next);
    visited.remove(next);
```

As I see there is a recursion `permute(..)` function before reaching them !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try to understand what the **permute**() function does. It juggles two vectors: *unvisited* and *visited*. In the execution of **permute**(), the function will take an element from *unvisited* and move it to *visited*. Think of it as "building" a permutation.

For example:

```
Unvisited: 1, 5, 8
visited:
```

we move an element from *unvisited* to *visited*

```
Unvisited:  5, 8
visited: 1
```

Now to build the rest of the permutations that start with 1, we need to find the permutations of *unvisited*, or {5,8}. So we *recursively* call **permute()** to find the rest.

So what does

```
unvisited.add(i,next);
visited.remove(next);
```

do ?

As each permutation is being built, the function is modifying a **unified/common/shared** source of data: the **vectors**. They are constantly being modified as elements are shifted from *unvisited* to *visited*. However, we need to **reset** these vectors to find the rest of the permutations. In the example above, we need to *put **1** back* to *unvisited* find the permutations that start with **5**, or **8**. So we:

```
unvisited.add(i,next); //add it back to unvisited in its original position
```

and

```
visited.remove(next); //remove it from visited.
```

Comment: Many Thanks, but my question is related to recursion logic, is when unvisited.add(i,next);
visited.remove(next);
are called if we call permute() function and back to the start each time before reaching them ..

Comment: sorry could you clarify your question? after moving an element from unvisited to visited, we call permute() because we need to find the permutations of the smaller set of items in unvisited. 
AFTER finding those permutations, we reset the unvisited/visited vectors by calling: unvisited.add(i,next); visited.remove(next);

Comment: I am sorry, I mean when calling permute() inside itself, everything after the inner permute() will not execute, right ?

Comment: ah i see. Actually, they will execute when permute() is finished. Granted, that may take a while, but the if(unvisited.isEmpty()) check guarantees that the recursion will eventually reach an end, and after that, the stack is rewinded and the lines: unvisited.add(i,next); visited.remove(next); get executed.

Comment: @Bader, if this has answered your question then I'd appreciate it if you would mark it as the correct answer. If not, then please ask more.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember about recursion is that when the method is called again, the following lines are not executed until that call is satisfied.

In this case **permute()** is called first by main, it checks to see if we're done (is unvisited empty) and eventually comes to the **permute(unvisited,visited);** line.

At this point the first running of **permute()** is put on hold and the second running takes over until at the nth running, it finds unvisited is empty and that running completes.

When the nth running closes, the nth-1 running picks up and then executes the two lines you asked about (which applepie explained) and then it to completes, returning control back to the nth-2 and so on until all the runnings are done.